# BQ297xy Overcurrent protection

Tags: current, battery-charging, battery-operated, current-limiting

Can someone explaine to me how dose this overcurrent protection works and how to calculate it?
[BQ297xy Schematics](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2971.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the datasheet:

> The discharge overcurrent detection voltage (VOCD) is measured between
>   V–and VSS pins and triggered when the V2 voltage is increased above
>   VOCD threshold with respect to VSS. This delta voltage once satisfied
>   will trigger an internal timer tOCDD before the DOUT output drive
>   transitions from high to low.

There is no user setting where he/she can individually change the settings. The thresholds can be either set at the factory or use parts with pre fixed factory thresholds.